# How to get Heroku to accept .mjs files (JS that uses modules)?

Tags: node.js, heroku, ecmascript-6, module

I have a few JS modules that are written using the latest ES6 module syntax, so the files are stored with the .mjs suffix. I want to run this on Heroku without using Babel to transpile into older syntax, but don't see a way to do this. I know that i have to give the node command line a special argument  --experimental-modules to get this to work, but don't see how you do this on Heroku. I can't be the first person to try modules, and the .mjs suffix was created by the node.js team so as to disambiguate old style vs. new style ES6 module code.

tried creating a package.json file specifying node 11.x, but clearly that isn't enough.

{
  "name": "tic-tac-toe-server",
  "description": "the server side of a tic tac toe application",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "11.x"
  }
}

I get an error that:
 The 'heroku/nodejs' buildpack is set on this application, but was
remote:  !     unable to detect a Node.js codebase.
remote:  !
remote:  !     A Node.js app on Heroku requires a 'package.json' at the root of
remote:  !     the directory structu

Comment: have you found any solution about this @Edward